# Могу ли я добавить тесты с методом main()?

Tags: java

Имеется тула, написанная на Java. Могу ли я в папку с тестами добавить несколько перформанс-тестов, каждый с методом main()? Т.е. при запуске jar'ника, сгенеренного сборкой, не может ли запуститься один из этих тестов вместо стандартного метода main()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс main метод которого будет выполнен, или задается в манифесте или укзывается в коммандной строке. Так что нет, ваши тестовые методы не запустятся, если вы только специально не запустите их.